# How to extract the highlighted info from the html tags using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I just want to scrape a website and extract the "Author Name" which is inside the   tag as highlighted in the image. How to do it using python3? I am having difficulty as the author's name is within multiple tags. [(image with the highlighted part)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjEgq.png)

Here is the code I have written to extract the 'Title' and 'Date'. Now, I want to extract the author name.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from htmldate import find_date 

url = "https://indianexpress.com/article/business/companies/market-surges- 
after-report-says-amazon-looking-at-40-in-reliance-retail-6591325/"
page = urlopen(url)
#print(page)
html_bytes = page.read()
html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
#print(html)

title_index = html.find("<title>")
start_index = title_index + len("<title>")
end_index = html.find("</title>")
title = html[start_index:end_index]
print(title)

date = find_date(url)
print(date)
```

Comment: What did you try ? Can you share your code and the URL.

Comment: I have updated the code in my post!

Answer (score 0):

Below are the python code to extract author name.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
fb_url = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/indianexpress').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(fb_url,'lxml')
data = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')
data = json.loads(data.text)
print(data['name'])
```